# how to generate two numbers between 0 and 4 in javascript, but make sure the numbers aren't the same

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate two numbers between 0 and 4 in javascript, but I don't want the two numbers to be the same. Any thoughts?

currently working with

```
state.blue_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
state.red_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
if(state.blue_id == state.red_id){
        ???????
    }
```

Comment: Create an array [0,1,2,3,4]. Then use `splice` to remove a random number from the array: `state.blue_id = yourArray.splice(Math.random() * yourArray.length, 1);` Repeat

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Rejection" is the standard way to handle this:

```js
state.blue_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
state.red_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
while(state.blue_id == state.red_id){
        state.red_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    }
```

Comment: Why does this no-effort question deserve an answer? And why haven't you closed it as a duplicate of one of the many "unique random numbers" question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `while`?

```
while (state.blue_id === state.red_id) {
    state.blue_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    state.red_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
}
```

Comment: Why does this no-effort question deserve an answer? And why haven't you closed it as a duplicate of one of the many "unique random numbers" question?